# how do I call all the keys of a json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code:

```
<body>
  <script type="application/json" src="Data0012.json"></script>
    <div><select id="selector"></select></div>
        <div class="chart"></div>
        <div class="equation"></div>
        <div class="equation"></div>




    <script>
      function loadJSON(filePath, callback) {
      var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      xobj.open('GET', filePath, true);
      xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}
loadJSON("Data0012.json", function(text){
    const data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
});

// Get object key
//const keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Stored data
//localStorage.setItem('keys', keys);

// Call method to get stored data when in different scripts
const keys = localStorage.getItem('keys');

console.log(keys)

    </script
```

and I have this json

```
{
    "-162.65": {
        "Player": "Gdlachance",
        "Hands": "44",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "13",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-162.65",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "50"
    },
    "-162.27": {
        "Player": "paramasivum",
        "Hands": "40",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "9",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-162.27",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "67"
    },
    "-157.32": {
        "Player": "Fairline69",
        "Hands": "49",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "25",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-157.32",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "17"
    },
    "-51.20": {
        "Player": "Matthinio-10",
        "Hands": "34",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "40",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-51.20",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "80"
    }}
```

that code gives me the first column ("-162.65", "-162,67","157.32" ......) and the problem is that I whant the second column of json

> "Player",
> "Hands",
> "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)",
> "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100"
> "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)":

**how can I call all the keys of json?**  I cant modify the json (I cant add code or whatever) and i dont know what are the values inside the columns (in a csv it would be the first line (cant call them explicitly) ... in a json it looks like if it was the second column), I hope I made my self understand.

Comment: You have to post only one problem a time. Now it is hard to understand what to you really want.

Comment: I just whant to call the second column of the json

Comment: You asking one column but posting the whole instance, but json don't have any columns. you have to post an output you need and point it is only for one key or for all keys

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: I still don't understand why do you  need the second property but not third or first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how do you decide what orderNum of property should be selected, but you can get any property by orderNum using this code

```
let orderNum=1;
console.log( data[Object.keys(data)[orderNum]]); //  "Player": "Fairline69",...
```

Comment: thanks, error say's data is not defined ... I think callback is async, how can I make it sync?